# Why do mount points sometimes changed?

Tags: boot, mount

I have two SAN devices `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb`;

```
Disk /dev/sda: 100 GiB, 107374182400 bytes, 209715200 sectors
Disk model: Virtual disk    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 4D63EAE4-196D-4EF2-BACA-2141E63DB0F6

Disk /dev/sdb: 1000 GiB, 1073741824000 bytes, 2097152000 sectors
Disk model: Virtual disk    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

But sometimes `/dev/sda` is mounted into `/dev/sdb` after reboot.
How can I prevent it from being changed?

#### Normal

```
/dev/sda2  ext4  976M  203M  707M  23% /boot
/dev/sdb   ext4  984G  9.9G  924G   2% /workspace
```

#### Abnormal

```
/dev/sdb2  ext4  976M  203M  707M  23% /boot
```

And here is the `/etc/fstab`

```
/dev/disk/by-id/dm-uuid-LVM-K680yYzEVuI9918TZkE1xLA9ArCLzJlDiU7cnVQoJxhLQcn5D4e8Xu05Vs4CWt4P / ext4 defaults 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/a1b97ff4-3862-4c49-8b65-8618dd32f1ff /boot ext4 defaults 0 0
/swap.img       none    swap    sw      0       0
/dev/sdb /workspace ext4 defaults 0 0
```

Comment: The devices are given letter designations based on the order they report themselves to the OS. Sometimes one may be 0.0001ms faster than the other and result in an assignment mixup. It’s generally better to use the UUID whenever possible 

Comment: That should be an answer, not a comment.